# Calculate Number of Minutes Between Two times Gravity Forms WP

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I am working with Wordpress ang Gravity Forms. I have two time fields and one nuber field. Number field is in minutes and must be number of minutes between two times.

Example:
Field 1 (time): **03:20**

Field 2 (time): **04:20**

Calculated field:
Field 3 (number of minutes between field 1 and field 3): **60**

I found something very similar but is code for Calculate Number of Days Between Two Dates:

```
<?php
/**
* Gravity Wiz // Calculate Number of Days Between Two Gravity Form Date Fields
*
* Allows you to calculated the number of days between two Gravity Form date fields and populate that number into a
* field on your Gravity Form.
*
* @version   1.1
* @author    David Smith <david@gravitywiz.com>
* @license   GPL-2.0+
* @link      https://gravitywiz.com/calculate-number-of-days-between-two-dates/
* @copyright 2013 Gravity Wiz
*/
class GWDayCount {
    private static $script_output;
    function __construct( $args ) {
        extract( wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'form_id'          => false,
            'start_field_id'   => false,
            'end_field_id'     => false,
            'count_field_id'   => false,
            'include_end_date' => true,
            ) ) );
        $this->form_id        = $form_id;
        $this->start_field_id = $start_field_id;
        $this->end_field_id   = $end_field_id;
        $this->count_field_id = $count_field_id;
        $this->count_adjust   = $include_end_date ? 1 : 0;
        add_filter( "gform_pre_render_{$form_id}", array( &$this, 'load_form_script') );
        add_action( "gform_pre_submission_{$form_id}", array( &$this, 'override_submitted_value') );
    }
    function load_form_script( $form ) {
        // workaround to make this work for < 1.7
        $this->form = $form;
        add_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', array( &$this, 'add_init_script' ) );
        if( self::$script_output )
            return $form;
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            window.gwdc = function( options ) {
                this.options = options;
                this.startDateInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.startFieldId );
                this.endDateInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.endFieldId );
                this.countInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.countFieldId );
                this.init = function() {
                    var gwdc = this;
                    // add data for "format" for parsing date
                    gwdc.startDateInput.data( 'format', this.options.startDateFormat );
                    gwdc.endDateInput.data( 'format', this.options.endDateFormat );
                    gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    gwdc.startDateInput.change( function() {
                        gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    } );
                    gwdc.endDateInput.change( function() {
                        gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    } );
                    $( '#ui-datepicker-div' ).hide();
                }
                this.getDayCount = function() {
                    var startDate = this.parseDate( this.startDateInput.val(), this.startDateInput.data('format') )
                    var endDate = this.parseDate( this.endDateInput.val(), this.endDateInput.data('format') );
                    var dayCount = 0;
                    if( !this.isValidDate( startDate ) || !this.isValidDate( endDate ) )
                        return '';
                    if( startDate > endDate ) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        var diff = endDate - startDate;
                        dayCount = diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000 ); // secs * mins * hours * milliseconds
                        dayCount = Math.round( dayCount ) + this.options.countAdjust;
                        return dayCount;
                    }
                }
                this.parseDate = function( value, format ) {
                    if( !value )
                        return false;
                    format = format.split('_');
                    var dateFormat = format[0];
                    var separators = { slash: '/', dash: '-', dot: '.' };
                    var separator = format.length > 1 ? separators[format[1]] : separators.slash;
                    var dateArr = value.split(separator);
                    switch( dateFormat ) {
                    case 'mdy':
                        return new Date( dateArr[2], dateArr[0] - 1, dateArr[1] );
                    case 'dmy':
                        return new Date( dateArr[2], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[0] );
                    case 'ymd':
                        return new Date( dateArr[0], dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[2] );
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                this.populateDayCount = function() {
                    this.countInput.val( this.getDayCount() ).change();
                }
                this.isValidDate = function( date ) {
                    return !isNaN( Date.parse( date ) );
                }
                this.init();
            }
        })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php
        self::$script_output = true;
        return $form;
    }
    function add_init_script( $return ) {
        $start_field_format = false;
        $end_field_format = false;
        foreach( $this->form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
                $start_field_format = $field['dateFormat'] ? $field['dateFormat'] : 'mdy';
            if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
                $end_field_format = $field['dateFormat'] ? $field['dateFormat'] : 'mdy';
        }
        $script = "new gwdc({
                formId:             {$this->form['id']},
                startFieldId:       {$this->start_field_id},
                startDateFormat:    '$start_field_format',
                endFieldId:         {$this->end_field_id},
                endDateFormat:      '$end_field_format',
                countFieldId:       {$this->count_field_id},
                countAdjust:        {$this->count_adjust}
            });";
        $slug = implode( '_', array( 'gw_display_count', $this->start_field_id, $this->end_field_id, $this->count_field_id ) );
        GFFormDisplay::add_init_script( $this->form['id'], $slug, GFFormDisplay::ON_PAGE_RENDER, $script );
        // remove filter so init script is not output on subsequent forms
        remove_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', array( &$this, 'add_init_script' ) );
        return $return;
    }
    function override_submitted_value( $form ) {
        $start_date = false;
        $end_date = false;
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
                $start_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );
            if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
                $end_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );
        }
        if( $start_date > $end_date ) {
            $day_count = 0;
        } else {
            $diff = $end_date - $start_date;
            $day_count = $diff / ( 60 * 60 * 24 ); // secs * mins * hours
            $day_count = round( $day_count ) + $this->count_adjust;
        }
        $_POST["input_{$this->count_field_id}"] = $day_count;
    }
    static function parse_field_date( $field ) {
        $date_value = rgpost("input_{$field['id']}");
        $date_format = empty( $field['dateFormat'] ) ? 'mdy' : esc_attr( $field['dateFormat'] );
        $date_info = GFCommon::parse_date( $date_value, $date_format );
        if( empty( $date_info ) )
            return false;
        return strtotime( "{$date_info['year']}-{$date_info['month']}-{$date_info['day']}" );
    }
}
# Configuration
new GWDayCount( array(
    'form_id'        => 16,
    'start_field_id' => 1,
    'end_field_id'   => 2,
    'count_field_id' => 4
) );
```

So far i came to that but i still have problems with date format:

```
class GWDayCount {
    private static $script_output;
    function __construct( $args ) {
        extract( wp_parse_args( $args, array(
            'form_id'          => false,
            'start_field_id'   => false,
            'end_field_id'     => false,
            'count_field_id'   => false,
            'include_end_date' => true,
            ) ) );
        $this->form_id        = $form_id;
        $this->start_field_id = $start_field_id;
        $this->end_field_id   = $end_field_id;
        $this->count_field_id = $count_field_id;
        $this->count_adjust   = $include_end_date ? 1 : 0;
        add_filter( "gform_pre_render_{$form_id}", array( &$this, 'load_form_script') );
        add_action( "gform_pre_submission_{$form_id}", array( &$this, 'override_submitted_value') );
    }
    function load_form_script( $form ) {
        // workaround to make this work for < 1.7
        $this->form = $form;
        add_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', array( &$this, 'add_init_script' ) );
        if( self::$script_output )
            return $form;
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            window.gwdc = function( options ) {
                this.options = options;
                this.startDateInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.startFieldId );
                this.endDateInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.endFieldId );
                this.countInput = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.countFieldId );

                startDateInput1 = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.startFieldId );
                endDateInput2 = $( '#input_' + this.options.formId + '_' + this.options.endFieldId );

                this.init = function() {
                    var gwdc = this;
                    // add data for "format" for parsing date
                    gwdc.startDateInput.data( 'format', this.options.startDateFormat );
                    gwdc.endDateInput.data( 'format', this.options.endDateFormat );
                    gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    gwdc.startDateInput.change( function() {
                        gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    } );
                    gwdc.endDateInput.change( function() {
                        gwdc.populateDayCount();
                    } );
                    $( '#ui-datepicker-div' ).hide();
                }
                this.getDayCount = function() {
                    var startDate = this.parseDate( this.startDateInput.val(), this.startDateInput.data('format') )
                    min1 = startDateInput1;


                    var endDate = this.parseDate( this.endDateInput.val(), this.endDateInput.data('format') );


                    var dayCount = 0;
                    if( !this.isValidDate( startDate ) || !this.isValidDate( endDate ) )
                        return 'neki ni kul';
                    if( startDate > endDate ) {
                        return 0;
                    } else {
                        var diff = endDate - startDate;
                        dayCount = diff ;
                        var test = min1;
                        dayCount = Math.round( dayCount ) + this.options.countAdjust;
                        return test;
                    }
                }

                this.parseDate = function( value, format ) {
                    if( !value )
                        return false;
                    format = format.split('_');
                    var dateFormat = format[0];
                    var separators = { slash: ':', dash: '-', dot: '.' };
                    var separator = format.length > 1 ? separators[format[1]] : separators.slash;
                    var dateArr = value.split(separator);
                    switch( dateFormat ) {
                    case 'mdy':
                        return new Date( 0, dateArr[0] - 1, dateArr[1] );
                    case 'dmy':
                        return new Date( 0, dateArr[1] - 1, dateArr[0] );
                    case 'ymd':
                        return new Date( dateArr[0], dateArr[1] - 1, 0 );
                    }
                    return false;
                }
                this.populateDayCount = function() {
                    this.countInput.val( this.getDayCount() ).change();
                }
                this.isValidDate = function( date ) {
                    return !isNaN( Date.parse( date ) );
                }
                this.init();
            }
        })(jQuery);
        </script>

        <?php
        self::$script_output = true;
        return $form;
    }
    function add_init_script( $return ) {
        $start_field_format = false;
        $end_field_format = false;
        foreach( $this->form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
                $start_field_format = $field['dateFormat'] ? $field['dateFormat'] : 'mdy';
            if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
                $end_field_format = $field['dateFormat'] ? $field['dateFormat'] : 'mdy';
        }
        $script = "new gwdc({
                formId:             {$this->form['id']},
                startFieldId:       {$this->start_field_id},
                startDateFormat:    '$start_field_format',
                endFieldId:         {$this->end_field_id},
                endDateFormat:      '$end_field_format',
                countFieldId:       {$this->count_field_id},
                countAdjust:        {$this->count_adjust}
            });";
        $slug = implode( '_', array( 'gw_display_count', $this->start_field_id, $this->end_field_id, $this->count_field_id ) );
        GFFormDisplay::add_init_script( $this->form['id'], $slug, GFFormDisplay::ON_PAGE_RENDER, $script );
        // remove filter so init script is not output on subsequent forms
        remove_filter( 'gform_init_scripts_footer', array( &$this, 'add_init_script' ) );
        return $return;
    }
    function override_submitted_value( $form ) {
        $start_date = false;
        $end_date = false;
        foreach( $form['fields'] as &$field ) {
            if( $field['id'] == $this->start_field_id )
                $start_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );
            if( $field['id'] == $this->end_field_id )
                $end_date = self::parse_field_date( $field );
        }
        if( $start_date > $end_date ) {
            $day_count = 0;
        } else {
            $diff = $end_date - $start_date;
            $day_count = $diff; // secs * mins * hours
            $day_count = round( $day_count ) + $this->count_adjust;
        }
        $_POST["input_{$this->count_field_id}"] = $day_count;
    }
    static function parse_field_date( $field ) {
        $date_value = rgpost("input_{$field['id']}");
        $date_format = empty( $field['dateFormat'] ) ? 'mdy' : esc_attr( $field['dateFormat'] );
        $date_info = GFCommon::parse_date( $date_value, $date_format );
        if( empty( $date_info ) )
            return false;
        return strtotime( "{$date_info['year']}-{$date_info['month']}-{$date_info['day']}" );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It isn't clear what you're asking for. Please provide the users on the platform with an indication of what you're trying to achieve, what you've tried so far and any errors that you came across when making those attempts.

Comment: IT could not be clearer. I want minutes between time and not days between two days.

Answer (score 0):

We (Gravity Wiz) have a plugin called GF Date Time Calculator that does. It is available by request for Gravity Perks license-holders. Here's a quick video of how it works.

http://screencast.com/t/ya7Dd5rm0SSf